# Error Invalid Regular Expression Escape while Allow Special Characters Options

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to validate a string to ensure it only contains certain characters using a function in my TypeScript project. The function takes a string and an options object as arguments, with the options specifying which characters are allowed.

Here's the function:

```
/**
 * Validates a string to ensure it only contains allowed characters.
 * @param {string} name - The string to validate.
 * @param {Object} [options] - The options to use for validation.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowNumbers=false] - Whether to allow numbers.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowSpecialCharacters=false] - Whether to allow special characters.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowSpaces=false] - Whether to allow spaces.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowUnderscores=false] - Whether to allow underscores.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowDashes=false] - Whether to allow dashes.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowPunctuation=false] - Whether to allow punctuation.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowCyrillic=false] - Whether to allow Cyrillic characters.
 * @param {boolean} [options.allowNonLatin=false] - Whether to allow non-Latin characters.
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the string is valid or not.
 */
interface IValidateNameOptions {
  allowNumbers?: boolean;
  allowSpecialCharacters?: boolean;
  allowSpaces?: boolean;
  allowUnderscores?: boolean;
  allowDashes?: boolean;
  allowPunctuation?: boolean;
  allowCyrillic?: boolean;
  allowNonLatin?: boolean;
}

interface IValidateName {
  (name: string, options?: IValidateNameOptions): boolean;
}

export const validateName: IValidateName = (
  name,
  options = {
    allowNumbers: false,
    allowSpecialCharacters: false,
    allowSpaces: false,
    allowUnderscores: false,
    allowDashes: false,
    allowPunctuation: false,
    allowCyrillic: false,
    allowNonLatin: false,
  },
) => {
  let regexStr = `^[a-zA-Z`;

  if (options.allowNonLatin) {
    regexStr += `\\p{L}`;
  }
  if (options.allowNumbers) {
    regexStr += `0-9`;
  }
  if (options.allowSpecialCharacters) {
    regexStr += `\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\_\\=\\+\\[\\]\\{\\}\\|\\\\\\;\\:\\'\\,\\.\\/\\<\\>\\?`;
  }
  if (options.allowSpaces) {
    regexStr += `\\s`;
  }
  if (options.allowUnderscores) {
    regexStr += `\\_`;
  }
  if (options.allowDashes) {
    regexStr += `\\-`;
  }
  if (options.allowPunctuation) {
    regexStr += `\\p{P}`;
  }
  if (options.allowCyrillic) {
    regexStr += `\\p{Cyrillic}`;
  }
  regexStr += `]+$`;

  const regex = new RegExp(regexStr, 'u');
  return regex.test(name);
};
```

Here is jest test:

```
it('should return true when name is valid and allowSpecialCharacters is true', () => {
  expect(validateName('Deri!', { allowSpecialCharacters: true })).toBe(true);
});
```

and here is error test:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/validateName.test.ts
  ✓ should return true when name is valid (3 ms)
  ✓ should return false when name is invalid (6 ms)
  ✕ should return true when name is valid and allowSpecialCharacters is true (2 ms)

  ● should return true when name is valid and allowSpecialCharacters is true

    SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\[\]\{\}\|\\\;\:\'\,\.\/\<\>\?]+$/: Invalid escape
        at new RegExp (<anonymous>)

      69 |   regexStr += `]+$`;
      70 |
    > 71 |   const regex = new RegExp(regexStr, 'u');
         |                 ^
      72 |   return regex.test(name);
      73 | };
      74 |

      at validateName (src/lib/validateName.ts:71:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/validateName.test.ts:41:22)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.536 s
Ran all test suites.
```

However, I keep getting an "invalid escape" error when I try to use the function, even though I've escaped all the special characters. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

answer explanation and a correct RegExp code

Comment: You might want to know that JavaScript (and hence TypeScript) do have [a slash-escaping function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw).

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the `'u'` option. Don't know exactly what changes with that (other than allowing unicode escapes) but it seems like it treats escape characters a bit differently.

The thing is inside `[]` you don't need to escape special characters, with a few exceptions. Also, to write raw strings i Javascript you can use ``` String.raw`` ``` .

So this should work:

```js
if (options.allowSpecialCharacters) {
    regexStr += String.raw`!@#$%^&*()\-_=+[\]{}|\\;:',./<>?`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I add special characters to **`** (backtick)? It's already being used to define a string using template literals.The backslash by itself and double backslashes are not working for backtick. What other characters do I need to escape?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your escaped characters are not specials in JavaScript. When you use Unicode mode with `u` flag, you cannot escape non-special characters "just in case". This is forbidden to ensure the possibility to add special escape sequences in future.

Compare:

```js
console.log(/:/); // No errors.
console.log(/\:/); // No errors as there is no u flag.
console.log(/\:/u); // Throws error.
```

So you only need to escape `[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )`, or even less inside `[]`.

See https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping and https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges#escaping-in- .

Comment: The code snippet is not very helpful. I know what you meant with it, though. Could you try correcting it?

Comment: @vr. Is it better now? Could you advise a correction? Maybe you can correct it by an editing?

Comment: Actually, only `-`, `]` and `\ ` needs to be escaped (`^` too, if it is placed before everything else). The rest are considered literal in a character class: `console.log(/[[$^|?*+()]/u); // /[[^$|?*+()]/u`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in the browser you will get the same

```js
const reg1 = /^[a-zA-Z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\[\]\{\}\|\\\;\:\'\,\.\/\<\>\?]+$/u
console.log(reg1)
```

the problem is you have specified - /u
Which means its expecting backslash characters to preceed with the u like this

this works:

```js
// \u003a === :
const reg = /\u003a/u
const matched = ' :'.match(reg)
console.log(matched)
```